# Difference between PageRequest obj & Page in Spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Could anyone explain the difference between PageRequest and Page in Spring boot?

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand about the differences between them? They seem to be well explained in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The main and important difference between [PageRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html) and [Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) is that

`Page` requires a `List<T>` to iterate over it and uses this `List<T>` as a source to retrieve a `Slice`(a small part or chuck) from it.

`PageRequest` is directly executed at BD and retrieves a `Slice` from it.